# HSQLDB update null entries with the previous not null value

Tags: sql, hsqldb

How can I update the null values from all entries with the previous not null row?

For example:

```
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  create_date date
);
```

Actual entries

```
id  create_date
2   2018-12-03
3   NULL
4   2018-12-04
5   NULL
6   NULL
```

Table entries after update:

```
id  create_date
2   2018-12-03
3   2018-12-03
4   2018-12-04
5   2018-12-04
6   2018-12-04
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the MAX value for CREATE_DATE from the rows that have a smaller ID than the current (updating) row. Use this max value to update the rows with NULL values. It's quite simple and doesn't need window functions.

```
UPDATE USERS U SET
  CREATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(CREATE_DATE) FROM USERS USUB WHERE USUB.ID < U.ID) 
  WHERE U.CREATE_DATE IS NULL
```

The above statement assumes the dates are in ascending order with respect to the ID (your example). If that is not the case, you can select the CREATE_DATE for exactly the last not null value with this statement.

```
UPDATE USERS U SET 
 CREATE_DATE = (SELECT CREATE_DATE FROM USERS USUB WHERE USUB.ID < U.ID AND USUB.CREATE_DATE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY USUB.ID DESC LIMIT 1) 
 WHERE U.CREATE_DATE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL standard, you can use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(create_date, lag(create_date ignore nulls) over (order by id)) as imputed_create_date
from t;
```

That option is not supported in all databases.  So an alternative is to assign a grouping to each row based on the number of non-`NULL` values up to that row.  Then, the non-`NULL` value can be spread over the group:

```
select t.*,
       max(create_date) over (partition by grp) as imputed_create_date
from (select t.*,
             count(create_date) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: It returns: "bad SQL grammar [select t.*, max(create_date) over (partition by grp) as imputed_create_date from (select t.*, count(create_date) over (order by id) as grp from t ) t] unexpected token: ("

Comment: @Valip . . . I don't think HSQLDB supports window functions.  You might want to upgrade to a database more inline with SQL standards.